# Make a new vector using elements of list and another vector interchengeably

Tags: r, list, vector, sequence, plyr

I have a list with 20 elements each contains a vector of 2 numbers. I have also generated a sequence of numbers (20). Now I would like to construct 1 long vector that would first list the elements of `intervals[[1]]` and the first element of `newvals[1]`, later `intervals[[2]]`, `newvals[2]` etc etc
Help will be much appreciated. I think `plyr` package might be helpful although I am not sure how to structure it.  help will be much appreciated!

```
s1 <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.05)
    intervals <- Map(c, s1[-length(s1)], s1[-1])
    intervals[[length(intervals)]][2] <- intervals[[length(intervals)]][2]+0.1

newvals <- seq(1,length(intervals),1)

#### HERE I WOULD LIKE TO HAVE A VECTOR IN THE FOLLOWING PATTERN 
####UP TO THE LAST ELEMENT OF THE LIST:

stringreclass <- c(intervals[[1]],newvals[1]), .... , intervals[[20]],newvals[20])
```

Comment: so this? `unlist(Map(c, intervals, newvals))`

Comment: yes indeed, perfect! thank you :)